# How to use std::ostringstream to check the output?

Tags: c++

I made code below to check the output.

```
ostringstream oss;
    Fraction f12{1, 2};
    oss << "fraction f12 is " << f12 << '\n';
    string result = oss.str();
    cout << result << '\n';
    std::string expected{ "fraction f12 is 1/2\n" };
    cout << expected << endl;
    if(oss.str() == expected)
        cout << "The strings match...\n";
    else
        cout << "The strings don't match.\n";
```

However, the output is below

```
fraction f12 is 1/2


fraction f12 is 1/2

The strings don't match.
```

I think f12 is cause, but I do not have idea.
How can I make it "The strings match..."?

Comment: There seems to be three newlines between the first line of output and the second, and only two between the second and third line. This could indicate a problem. I suggest you use a debugger to look at the actual contents of `oss.str()` (or `result`) and `expected`.

Comment: you should post the operator<< for Fraction

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a [mcve] (with emphasis on the *minimal* part).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didnt not post all the code. In particular, the code that makes the two strings different is missing. However, looking at the output, we can see that `result` has two `\n` while `expected` has only one (in the output we see one line break more due to the `endl`/`\n` when you print the two).

I suppose your `<<` for `Fraction` has something like this:

```
out << fraction.denominator << "/" << fraction.numerator << "\n";
```

And you can either change that or compare `result` to

```
std::string expected{ "fraction f12 is 1/2\n\n" };
                                          // ^^
```